# Group by 7 day interval postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, intervals

I know this is a common question, but I couldn't find something that matches my case. I have this data:

```
  id |    obs     
----+------------
  1 | 2018-01-01
  2 | 2018-01-02
  3 | 2018-01-03
  4 | 2018-01-04
  5 | 2018-01-05
  6 | 2018-01-06
  7 | 2018-01-07
  8 | 2018-01-15
  9 | 2018-01-20
 10 | 2018-02-03
 11 | 2018-02-04
 12 | 2018-02-05
 13 | 2018-02-06
 14 | 2018-02-06
```

I want this data to be grouped based on a 7 day interval. That is, the groups would be:

- Group 1: id 1 to 7
- Group 2: id 8 and 9
- Group 3: id 10 to 14

How is this query in PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please define "7-day interval".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proceed as follow:

- first, use a subquery to compare the date of the current record to the minimum date of the series; the difference in days between the dates divided by 7 gives you a first version of the group the record belong to (but for now group numbers are not necessarily consecutive)
- then, use `DENSE_RANK()` in an outer query to reassign group numbers as consecutive numbers:

Query:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    obs,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY gr) grp
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        obs,
        MIN(obs) OVER(),
        (obs - MIN(obs) OVER())::int/7 + 1 gr
    FROM mytable
) x
ODER BY id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/smy5EsmYSTeNtDNMTAZhr/5)**;

```
| id  | obs                      | grp |
| --- | ------------------------ | --- |
| 1   | 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 2   | 2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 3   | 2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 4   | 2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 5   | 2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 6   | 2018-01-06T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 7   | 2018-01-07T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |
| 8   | 2018-01-15T00:00:00.000Z | 2   |
| 9   | 2018-01-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2   |
| 10  | 2018-02-03T00:00:00.000Z | 3   |
| 11  | 2018-02-04T00:00:00.000Z | 3   |
| 12  | 2018-02-05T00:00:00.000Z | 4   |
| 13  | 2018-02-06T00:00:00.000Z | 4   |
| 14  | 2018-02-06T00:00:00.000Z | 4   |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group things based on a *gap* of seven days, use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_obs is null or prev_obs < obs - interval '7 day') over (order by obs) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(obs) over (order by obs) as prev_obs
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: @Fabi_Z . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?